# relative value of char variables

Tags: sql, group-by, char

I have a table with values of "yes", "No" and "N/A" for the variable ORGANIC
I can find the percentage for one of them individually but what I wont is a table with the percentage for yes, no and N/A

If it is just yes or no I know how to do it

```sql
select (1-Cast(t.yes as dec(32,2))/Count(*)) as no, 
  Cast(t.yes as dec(32,2))/Count(*) as yes, t.yes
from Products ,
  (Select Count(organic) as yes from Products
   where organic = 'yes') t

group by yes
```

the problem is when it has more than two outcomes

Any help?

Comment: What SQL platform are you using? Microsoft, MySQL, ...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
select
  a.organic,a.groupedcount/b.totalcount * 100 as percentage
from 
(select organic,count(*) groupedcount 
 from products 
 group by organic) a,
(select count(*) totalcount 
 from products) b
```

Or if you don't want to use ANSI-89:

```
select
  a.organic,a.groupedcount/b.totalcount * 100 as percentage
from 
(select organic,count(*) groupedcount 
 from products 
 group by organic) a 
CROSS JOIN (select count(*) totalcount 
 from products) b
```

will give exactly the same result

Comment: Never use implicit syntax in an answer (or in real life) even if, especially if), the OP used it in the question. That is a SQL antipattern and gets the down vote. We are not here to promote worst practices.

Comment: @Joaquim - You're welcome. If it's what you needed, please accept the answer so the rest of the community know it was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two options.

This one considers all options in the table but uses a subquery:

```
SELECT Organic, COUNT(*) AS Quantity, 100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products)
FROM Products
GROUP BY Organic
```

And this one only considers the tree options but uses no subqueries:

```
SELECT
100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Organic = 'yes' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS Yes,
100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Organic = 'no' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS No,
100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Organic = 'N/A' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS NA
FROM Products
```

Comment: @Joaquim, did this work for you? If it did, please mark it as accepted answer so we know this has been solved. Thanks.